# How to access macro of UIColor from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, macros, uicolor

There's a macro in objc file like below.

```
#define kSOME_COLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:100/255.0 green:100/255.0 blue:100/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

And i wanna access the macro from Swift.

```
self.someView.backgroundColor = kSOME_COLOR
```

But i got compile error `Use of unresolved identifier 'kNOTE_GREEN_COLOR'`
Is there any way.

Answer (score 1):

Leo is right you can not have Objective C like Macro in Swift. You can redefine them in your swift class.

Or if you would to use them from objective c Class only then you can do following
in your .m file implementation, and also make that public in header

```
+ (UIColor *)k_SOME_COLOR {
    return kSOME_COLOR;
}
```

in .h file

```
+ (UIColor *)k_SOME_COLOR;
```

in swift file

```
var someColor = Constants.k_SOME_COLOR() // Constants is class name
```

For this you need to use Swift Bridging header and include your constant class in bridging header, rest of conversion for calling Objective-C code is just magic by Swift.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no macro in Swift but you can achieve exactly the same result defining a constant as follow:

```
let someGrayColor = UIColor(red: 100.0/255.0, green: 100.0/255.0, blue: 100.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

self.someView.backgroundColor = someGrayColor
```